# Run a class instance as a thread by itself

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, timer

I have this piece of code:

```
Timeout s = new Timeout();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(s, 1000L); // fires after 1 second
```

How can I launch the following piece of code as a thread by itself? Would I need to pass the timer and Timeout to a Runnable and then start it? What happens if the thread's Run() ends before the timer is fired?

I am thinking of doing this instead:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Timeout s = new Timeout(); // Timeout is a runnable
        ses.schedule(s, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

but how do I exit the thread after the timeout? I run out of thread after a while

Thanks

Comment: This question didn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I'll give it a shot.

> How can I launch the following piece of code as a thread by itself?

In short...

Timeout.java

```
public class Timeout extends TimerTask {
    boolean isDone = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO something

        synchronized(this) {
            isDone=true;
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void join() throws InterruptedException {
        while(!this.isDone)
            this.wait();
    }
}
```

TimeoutRunner.java

```
public class TimerRunner implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Timeout timeout = new Timeout();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timeout, 1000L);

        try {
            timeout.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Run the TimeoutRunner using:

```
new Thread(new TimeoutRunner()).start();
```

The join method will block the thread until the timeout task has completed execution. At that time you can close the Timer. This is, however, a lot of thread creation, and IMO bad programming.

When you create a Timer instance, a thread is created to execute the Timeout#run() method. The timer has it's own run method that blocks until your task is ready for execution. After the given timeout period elapses, the timer unblocks and executes your timeout.

Your TimeoutRunner thread will block until the timeout operation completes. Only then can this thread die.

The Timer class is very limited. You need to create a new instance for every task. In my option, the ScheduledExecutorService is a better option. Keep the ScheduledExecutorService open for as long as you plan on executing tasks. If you need something like a scheduled cached thread pool, feel free to use this class from one of my open-source projects ([Scheduler](http://code.google.com/p/java-gearman-service/source/browse/trunk/src/org/gearman/util/Scheduler.java)). This works great with a cached thread pool.